# Viewbag Customizada, como fazer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso de uma Viewbag 'customizada', que traga o nome do professor e o id, referente a escola logada, para isto fiz:

```
ViewBag.ProfessorID = new SelectList(from u in db.Pessoas.OfType<Professor>() join v in db.EscolaProfessores on u.PessoaID equals v.ProfessorID where v.EscolaID== escola.EscolaID select u).ToList();
```

Códigos:
Buscar usuário ativo:

```
Escola escola = Repositories.Funcoes.GetUsuario();
```

Classes:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter de 3 a 255 caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    {...}

    //relacionamentos
    public int CidadeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
}

public class Professor : Pessoa
{

    //Relacionamentos
    public virtual ICollection<EscolaProfessor> Escolas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProfessorAluno> Alunos { get; set; }
}

public class Escola
{
    [Key]
    public int EscolaID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Razão Social")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a Razão Social")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A razão social deve ter de 3 a 255 caracteres")]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    {...}

    //relacionamentos
    public int CidadeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EscolaProfessor> Professores { get; set; }//Vários professores
    public virtual ICollection<EscolaAluno> Alunos { get; set; }//Vários alunos

}


public class EscolaProfessor
{
    [Key]
    public int EscolaProfessorID { get; set; }

    //Relaiconamentos
    [ForeignKey("Professor")]
    public int ProfessorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Escola")]
    public int EscolaID { get; set; }
    public virtual Escola Escola { get; set; }
}
```

e aqui o código na View:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfessorID, "Professor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ProfessorID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfessorID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

E ai na view, o Dropdownlist exibe os resultados da seguinte maneira:

`MinhaAplicacao.Models.Professor`

E não o nome deles.

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca a parte onde você exibe a `ViewBag.ProfessorID`, parece que o problema está na hora que você "pega" a `ViewBag` na view

Comment: @MarllonNasser vc diz para por o código da view? se for acabei de editar

Comment: sim..o problema é que você tá guardando a lista dentro da viewbag e não tá usando a viewBag na propria view...

Comment: E o que exatamente tenho que fazer ?

Comment: @FabioSouza Você quer que o drop down mostre `nome - id`? Algo como: `Jéferson - 550`. Ou é outra coisa?

Comment: Mostre apenas o nome, mas por trás cada usuário tenha sua id 'escondida' como normalmente é

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No momento da criação do [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.108).aspx), faltou colocar os dois campos que são elementos importantes na montagem do `select` do `html`, e fiz uma ajuste na sua `ViewBag` para `ViewBag.Professores`, porque, já tem um campo com esse nome, **exemplo**:

```
var result = from u in db.Pessoas.OfType<Professor>() 
    join v in db.EscolaProfessores on u.PessoaID equals v.ProfessorID 
    where v.EscolaID == escola.EscolaID select u;

ViewBag.Professores = new SelectList(result, "ProfessorID","Nome");
```

---

No `@Html.DropDownList`, também coloque o mesmo nome da `ViewBag` `Professores`, exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfessorID, "Professor",
           htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Professores", null, 
           htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfessorID, "", 
           new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

---

***Leitura:*** [Uma técnica simples para utilizar DropDownList no ASP.NET MVC](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/08/tecnica-simples-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc/)

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [SelectList Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.108).aspx)
- [ASP.Net MVC – ViewData, ViewBag e TempData](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/06/asp-net-mvc-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata/)

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio, deu certo!!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você não coloca a sua Lista no seu dropdown.

Ajusta sua lista antiga para retornar somente uma Collection.

```
var listaProfessores = from u in db.Pessoas.OfType<Professor>() join v in db.EscolaProfessores on u.PessoaID equals v.ProfessorID where v.EscolaID == escola.EscolaID select u;

ViewBag.ListaProfessores = listaProfessores;
```

E na view utilize a tal lista no seu dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfessorID, "Professor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownList("ProfessorID", new SelectList((IEnumerable<Professor>)ViewBag.ListaProfessores, "PessoaID", "Nome"), new { @class = "form-control" })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfessorID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
</div>
```

Mas eu recomendo que você crie uma `ViewModel` com uma propriedade `IEnumerable<Professor>` e passe essa informação para a view.